# long text printed on screen creating a horizontal line and going of of bounds while printing

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I am working on textarea where the user can enter text to create the letter. now if they keep typing continuously, it creates a lengthy string and once they save it in database, the same letter is available for print. Now while printing, it shows a very long horizontal bar. While printing, text is being cut off

I tried using the WRAP function of Function, but that creates extra `&nbsp;` Tags where they are not needed, Although in letter, there are couple of instances where they are needed. using the Following Code replaces all `&NBSP;`.

```
#Wrap(qryGetLetterDetails.letter,'([[:print:]])(&nbsp;)([[:print:]])','\1 \3','all'),75)#
```

My Next Approach was using the Custom Lib Function **WRAP** available on [CFLIB.org](http://www.cflib.org)

Again with this Tag, it generated the source HTML on screen while wrapping the Letter. It did not worked as expected.

I tried searching CSS ways to force to break word but in vain. I am using IE7+ versions only, No other Browser Support is provided.

Comment: How is the text being displayed to the user before printing? Is it just one long line in the browser too?

Comment: Yes, it is displayed a complete long line. Also while i see its print preview, i see the words only which are inside the page margin.

Answer (score -1):

can you try with

```
     #ReplaceList(qryGetLetterDetails.letter, "#chr(10)#,#chr(13)#", "<br />")#
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The problem faced by Gurpreet is that the user is typing long paragraphs without carraige returns.  Replacing carraige returns with html tags does not solve that problem.

Comment: @Dan, I am now using word-break:break-all; CSS Property,it does break but it will not follow standards as to where to cut down the words. it just cuts the words from inbetween what the ever the case it but keeps the text within the defined limits. definately not a solution but does not sems to find any other answer as of now.